# joined query to return data

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query which returns data only if the join exists. How do I return from the last joined table (#__unis) datas, even if there is no relationship between those tables without to write another query?

```
    select * from #__unis_faculties AS faculty
    join #__unis_subjects AS subject ON subject.faculty = faculty.id
    join #__unis AS uni ON  uni.id= subject.university
    where uni.id = 1
```

table structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `join`

```
   select * from #__unis_faculties AS faculty
 join #__unis_subjects AS subject ON subject.faculty = faculty.id
 right join #__unis AS uni ON  uni.id= subject.university
 where uni.id = 1
```

Comment: I have been trying before but the array is empty

Comment: can you provide a fiddle example ?

Comment: you have created fiddle but there was no data in it. can you make some sample data in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select * from #__unis_faculties AS faculty
join #__unis_subjects AS subject ON subject.faculty = faculty.id
left join #__unis AS uni ON  ( uni.id= subject.university AND uni.id = 1 )
```